# Using ':' for all range in an IF statement - Python

Tags: python, if-statement, eval

I am wondering how I can use the ':' symbol in an IF statement.
For example - if a condition is true, I want to use all values; else use only some values.

The code is-

```
If condition_true:
   data['column1'][:]
else:
   data['column1'][x:y]
```

I am wondering if I can use something like this-

```
If condition_true:
   var = ':'
else:
   var = 'x:y'
data['column1'][eval(var)]
```

But obviously this is not working with the eval function.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: use `slice(None)` and `slice(x,y)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to wrap the whole last statement and use `.format(...)` to inject your variable into the string.

```py
If condition_true:
   var = ':'
else:
   var = 'x:y'
eval("data['column1'][{}]".format(var))
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. The combination of eval and format helps!

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear~

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
new_data = data['column'] if condition_true else data['column'][x:y]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is much simpler and it works as well. I was struggling with the eval function though.